# CompassSusy Nested Grids not giving correct column widths/margins

Tags: css, width, sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I have a main grid setup with susy and then in the `footer` element I use Susy's `with-grid-settings()` mixin to generate a slightly different grid as follows:

```
footer
  +span-columns(5 omega, 5)
  +with-grid-settings(5, 174px ,20px ,0)
    +container
    @if $dev-mode-footer == true
      +susy-grid-background
    height: 240px
```

So `footer` should span all 5 of the main columns and include a new grid of slightly different widths and uses the `container` mixin to apply it.

So, then inside `footer` I have some `ul`'s which are set to span 1 column each but the margin left is practically doubled.

Here is the CSS:

```
footer
  .banner
    +span-columns(5 omega, 5)
    height: 187
    border-top: 3px solid $highlight-1
    border-bottom: 3px solid $highlight-1
    padding: 10px 0

    ul
      +pie-clearfix

    li
      +span-columns(1, 5)
      border-right: 1px dotted $highlight-2
      padding-left: 35px
```

and a picture of the outcome:

[image: Susy and wrong widths]

It justs seems like it is aligning to the wrong grid context. Is it something to do with the fact that both grids have the same number of columns or something?

Comment: Anyone able to help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how things work, sorry. It's really a conceptual problem. Susy helps you design to a grid, but the grid itself *does not exist anywhere*. Applying `container` does not establish anything besides a proper max-width. That container doesn't have any knowledge of the grid inside it. `with-grid-settings` is similarly unable to effect anything outside itself. Any items on the new grid must be passed inside the `with-grid-settings` mixin.

## Here's what you are actually doing:

First, `+span-columns(5 omega, 5)` doesn't do anything useful. You have just floated an item to the right, and applied 100% width. But block elements span their full context by default, so there is no real change - just extra code. The one effect you might want from this is clearing floats, but you should use `clearfix` for that instead.

Then, on the same element, `container` is simply setting a new `max-width`, and auto margins. That is, in fact, all a container is - and in this case you don't need it. New nested grids don't need new containers. All you need is `with-grid-settings`.

## Here's my guess on what you actually want:

```
footer
  +clearfix
  +with-grid-settings(5, 174px ,20px ,0)
    @if $dev-mode-footer == true
      +susy-grid-background
    height: 240px
    .banner
      +clearfix
      height: 187
      border-top: 3px solid $highlight-1
      border-bottom: 3px solid $highlight-1
      padding: 10px 0

      ul
        +pie-clearfix

      li
        +span-columns(1, 5)
        border-right: 1px dotted $highlight-2
        padding-left: 35px
```

You might also need to use `nth-omega(5n)` on the li.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. I understand that the grid doesn't actually exist. Confusing but does make sense.

My issue was I had parts of the code you posted above over two different files to split them and one had the with-grid-settings mixin used but the other didn't. That's all fixed.

Thanks for the tips on +container and spanning all columns. I have amended my sites code to reduce outputted code bloat due to those.

It all makes perfect sense really so thanks again!